# Postfix not logging authentication failures

Tags: postfix, rsyslog, fail2ban

I have a postfix server running on Ubuntu 18.04lts with authentication enabled.

(from main.cf)

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
```

I want to provision fail2ban to block attempts at brute forcing logins. I see burst of activity like this:

```
Jul  3 06:39:33 liv-e01-pg-inmail postfix/smtpd[27594]: disconnect from unknown[194.31.98.76] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 rset=1 quit=1 commands=3/4
```

(I believe that the "auth=0/1" indicates one failed attempt to authenticate.)

There are a several fail2ban recipes on the internet, however all the ones I have seen look for an explicit authentication failure report in the logs, e.g. from https://bobcares.com/blog/fail2ban-postfix-sasl/ :

```
Aug 31 22:23:52 hostxyz postfix/smtpd[38697]: warning: unknown[192.168.xx.xx]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
```

There are no such log entries being recorded on my host (checked mail.log, syslog and auth.log). Nor do I see successful authentication events being reported in the logs (but I can see the emails getting processed).

rsyslog is running with the default config:

```
auth,authpriv.*                 /var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none          -/var/log/syslog
kern.*                          -/var/log/kern.log
mail.*                          -/var/log/mail.log
```

What am I missing here?

** Update**

I **do** see successful authentication attempts in the mail.log - but no sign of failed logins.

Comment: What version of Postfix is in Ubuntu 18.04lts? An older version of Postfix may not have various patches that improve logging of SMTP AUTH failures.

Comment: I don't think it's due to an older version.  I've been running fail2ban rules matching that SASL LOGIN log entry from postfix on debian for over a decade, with postfix being upgraded many times over that period.  postfix definitely makes those log entries and rsyslog writes them to /var/log/mail.log (and mail.warn)

Comment: It's Postfix 3.3.0

Comment: I would like to advice you play around 
`debug_peer_list = 127.0.0.1` and `debug_peer_level` options in `main.cf`.
Not tested
See here - http://postfix.cs.utah.edu/DEBUG_README.html

Comment: Post your full main.cf, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out what is happenning.

First I tried experimenting:

- Accessing the service with a bad username/password produced the expected log entries (but postfix took several seconds to respond)
- Terminating the connection while waiting for postfix to respond still produced the expected log entries
- Terminating the connection after entring the username but before entering the assword produced the expected log entries

So I then set up tcpdump to listen for activity from one of the addresses which keeps triggering these events.

What I found was that the client was attempting to authenticate without first running STARTTLS, resulting in **503 5.5.1 Error: authentication not enabled**

Although this appears to pose little risk, and since all failed authentication attempts (including this one) result in a log entry containing "auth=0/[1-9]" I used that for my fail2ban filter.